# Are Virgin Galactic tourists asked to take a 6 to 8G centrifuge test to qualify, and if so, what's the point?

Tags: safety, sub-orbital, training, virgin-galactic, g-force

Regarding [sub-orbital spaceflights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sub-orbital_spaceflight) with [Virgin Galactic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virgin_Galactic),

claims that:

> Allegedly some travelers were asked to take a 6 to 8G centrifuge test to qualify

Is that true, and if so, what's the point?

Comment: Uninformed speculation would be that they want to weed out anybody who has health problems with high G-loads/being stuck in a confined space before they are having to abort a flight with paying customers, the rest of whom will want another flight. Also potentially acts as a commitment barrier- if you are prepared to subject yourself to the discomfort of the centrifuge you are probably serious about going through with the flight. Unrelated to the question but would bet the 'health/fitness guidance' 30 seconds later in the video is 'this flight has no toilet, eat accordingly'.

Comment: @GremlinWranger : How though is a "proper" spaceflight going to require endurance comparable to 6-8 gee? Why not just test with what you'd actually encounter on the flight? Safety margin?

Comment: @The_Sympathizer the max acceleration I’ve found quoted ([here](https://www.virgingalactic.com/learn/), in “Your flight to space”) is 3.5 G during the rocket burn once released from the carrier aircraft. Don’t know if there are other phases of flight with higher acceleration, be it in normal or emergency circumstances.

Comment: @jcaron Dead link...

Answer (score 3):

https://bis-space.com/membership/voyage/VoyageIssue8-Virgin%20Galactic.pdf confirms that:

> The Virgin Galactic spaceship is designed
> to fly almost anyone to space without the
> need for long term training. Passengers
> will have three days of extensive pre-flight
> training. This **may include flight simulation
> or centrifuge training to prepare for the
> g-forces**.

On the same PDF, it is mentioned that the reentry is 6g.

[image]

Note that according to https://www.topgear.com/car-news/big-reads/behind-scenes-virgin-galactic:

> The trajectory is very vertical, the burn is about a minute and you pull about **3.5–4g**.