# What percentage of the population can pass Virgin Galactic's training sessions for tourists to board a sub-orbital spaceflight?

Tags: safety, sub-orbital, training, virgin-galactic, g-force

I read on https://www.cnbc.com/2020/09/26/space-tourism-how-spacex-virgin-galactic-blue-origin-axiom-compete.html ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201126051920/https://www.cnbc.com/2020/09/26/space-tourism-how-spacex-virgin-galactic-blue-origin-axiom-compete.html)):

> Additionally, Virgin Galactic has said that passengers will spend three days training before a flight, while Blue Origin expects its passengers will train for just one day.

The three-day training [might be challenging to some extent](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/49269/1111).

What percentage of the population can pass Virgin Galactic's training sessions for tourists to board a [sub-orbital spaceflight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sub-orbital_spaceflight) with [Virgin Galactic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virgin_Galactic)? Ideally broken down by age group.